# Adding an image from Drawable using Bitmap and putting it to a new ParseUser

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-server

Been trying to put an image from my drawable into a newly added ParseUser.

But it doesn't add, due to line where I put the image into the user.(Without this line i works perfectly).

Parse doesn't return any LogErros on the toast, only that there is an error to it.

Here is the method:

private void addUser() {

```
    //object user
    ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
    user.setUsername(cadastroUsuario.getText().toString());
    user.setEmail(cadastroEmail.getText().toString());
    user.setPassword(cadastroSenha.getText().toString());
    user.put("nameUser", cadastroNome.getText().toString());


            //create image from drawable
            Bitmap imagem = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.ic_play_circle_filled);

            //comprimir no formato PNG
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            imagem.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 5, stream);

            //Cria um array de bytes da imagem
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            //Criar um arquivo com formato próprio do parse
            ParseFile arquivoParse = new ParseFile("imagempadrao.png", byteArray);

            //Monta o objeto para salvar no parse
            user.put("imagem", arquivoParse);

            //salvar dados do usuario
            user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(CadastroActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        abrirLoginUsuario();
                    } else {
                        ParseErros parseErros = new ParseErros();
                        String erro = parseErros.getErro(e.getCode());
                        //Toast.makeText(CadastroActivity.this, "Erro no cadstro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Toast.makeText(CadastroActivity.this, erro, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the File first, which assigns it a URL.  The file can't be attached to an object otherwise.

Comment: Hi, Like: "arquivoParse.saveInBackground();" ? I did that before the signup and it still didn't work.

Comment: That function is asynchronous. If you have other code that relies on it completing, it should go inside a completion handler.